# Integration of $ \int x^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

> $$ \int x^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx = ?$$

**My Attempt:**

by partial integration
$$ \int x^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx = \frac{x^{2} (2x-6)^{3/2}}{3}- \frac{2}{3} \int x(2x-6)^{3/2}dx$$
continuing partial integration
$$ = \frac{x^{2} (2x-6)^{3/2}}{3}- \frac{2}{3} \left[ \frac{x(2x-6)^{5/2}}{5} - \int \frac{(2x-6)^{5/2}}{5} dx\right]  $$
$$ = (x^{2}/3)(2x-6)^{3/2} - (2x/15)(2x-6)^{5/2} + (2/105)(2x-6)^{7/2} + C$$

Is this the correct and best/simplest answer?

Strangely, the multiple choices only include answers in the form:

$$ A(2x+6)^{7/2} + B(2x+6)^{5/2} + C(2x+6)^{3/2} + D$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is correct as soon as you change a sign (typo?):
the result can be written as
$$A(2x-6)^{7/2} + B(2x-6)^{5/2} + C(2x-6)^{3/2} + D$$

Note that
$$\frac{2x}{15}(2x-6)^{5/2}=\frac{2x-6+6}{15}(2x-6)^{5/2}=\frac{1}{15}(2x-6)^{7/2}+\frac{2}{5}(2x-6)^{5/2}.$$
Similarly, you can write  $\frac{x^2}{3}(2x−6)^{3/2}$ as a linear combination of $(2x-6)^{7/2}$, $(2x-6)^{5/2}$, and $(2x-6)^{3/2}$: 
$$\frac{x^2}{3}(2x−6)^{3/2}=\frac{(2x-6)^2/4+3(2x-6)+9}{3}(2x−6)^{3/2}
\\=\frac{1}{12}(2x−6)^{7/2}+(2x−6)^{5/2}+3(2x−6)^{3/2}.$$
Hence, your result can be written as
$$\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{15}+\frac{2}{105}\right)}_{1/28}(2x-6)^{7/2} + \underbrace{\left(1-\frac{2}{5}\right)}_{3/5}(2x-6)^{5/2} + 3(2x-6)^{3/2} + C.$$
However, the final result in that form can be obtained more easily by applying the substitution $t=\sqrt{2x-6}$. Then $x=\frac{t^2}{2}+3$, $dx=tdt$ and
$$\int x^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx =\frac{1}{4}\int (t^2+6)^2 t (t dt)=\int \left(\frac{t^6}{4}+3t^4+9t^2\right) dt\\
=\frac{t^7}{28}+\frac{3t^5}{5}+3t^3+C
=\frac{1}{28}(2x-6)^{7/2} + \frac{3}{5}(2x-6)^{5/2} + 3(2x-6)^{3/2} + C.$$

Comment: I think $2x+6$ must be $2x-6$, because $t=\sqrt{2x-6}$.

Comment: @farruhota Thanks. I edited my answer.

Comment: Also, after your statement "Hence, your result can be written as".

Comment: @farruhota Thanks again!!

Comment: You are welcome. +1. So, the answer to OP's question is negative, i.e. impossible, is not it?

Comment: @farruhota I think that there is a typo in OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:Substituting $$t=\sqrt{2x-6}$$ then we get $$x=\frac{t^2+6}{2}$$ then we get
$$dx=tdt$$

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Compare it with WA [answer](http://integrate%20(x%5E2(2x-6)%5E0.5)):
$$= (x^{2}/3)(2x-6)^{3/2} - (2x/15)(2x-6)^{5/2} + (2/105)(2x-6)^{7/2} + C=\\
(2x-6)^{3/2}\left(\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{2x(2x-6)}{15}+\frac{2(2x-6)^2}{105}\right)+C=\\
(2x-6)^{3/2}\cdot \frac{35x^2-28x^2+84x+8x^2-48x+72}{105}+C=\\
(2x-6)^{3/2}\cdot \frac{5x^2+12x+24}{35}+C=\\
2\sqrt{2}(x-3)^{3/2}\cdot \frac{5x^2+12x+24}{35}+C.$$
I don't think it can be transformed to the expected multiple choices with $2x+6$ as the binomial is under square root. So, I assume there is a typo in the source.

You can avoid the hard methods and calculate as follows:
$$\int x^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx = \frac14\int (2x)^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx = \frac14\int (2x-6+6)^{2} \sqrt{2x-6} dx = \\
\frac14\int (2x-6)^{2.5}dx+\frac14\int 12(2x-6)^{1.5}dx+\frac14\int 36(2x-6)^{0.5}dx=\\
\frac1{28}(2x-6)^{3.5}+\frac35(2x-6)^{2.5}+3(2x-6)^{1.5}+C.$$